# Angular call $http.get synchronous

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a snip code used get method in $http as below

```
generateFooter: function(){
            var footer;
            $http.get('/angular-admin/personalize-tenant').then(function(response){
                    var tenant = {name: response.data.name,
                        address: response.data.addresses[0]
                    };
                    var address = '<div>'+ tenant.address.street_name + '</div>'
                    +   '<div>' + tenant.address.house_number + '</div>'
                    +   '<div>' + tenant.address.house_name + '</div>'
                    +   '<div>' + tenant.address.postcode + '</div>'
                    +   '<div>' + tenant.address.city + '</div>'
                    +   '<div>' + tenant.address.province + '</div>'
                    +   '<div>' + tenant.address.country + '</div>';
                    footer ={"cols": [{
                        "wd": 100,
                        "rows": [{
                            "text": tenant.name,
                            "filtertext": {
                                "0": tenant.name
                            },
                            "position": "cell",
                            "required": true,
                            "id": "tenant-name"
                        }
                        ]
                    }],
                        "position": "row",
                        "type": "footer"
                        };
                    return footer;
                });
            return footer;
        },
```

The result return "undefined" value.

I want to value of footer will be returned when call $http.get method in synchronous successfully.

Thanks all,

Comment: With `$http` you can't block to wait until it returns the data. If that was the case, the entire UI (if not the browser) would freeze. So, when your most bottom `return footer` executes, `footer` is still undefined. When your other `return footer` executes, `footer` is defined, but you are not "returning" it to anything.

Comment: Are there any approachs to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you,

```
$http.get('/angular-admin/personalize-tenant').then(function(response){
                    var tenant = {name: response.data.name,
                    address: response.data.addresses[0]
                    };
```

Instead of above try below format.

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //In data object you can access the result.
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

If above doesn't work for you, tell me where you got problem.